# Can't kill EXCEL.EXE process after open and read excel file

Tags: c#, excel, com, process

I open and read data from excel by below flow:

```
ApplicationClass objApp = new ApplicationClass();  
Workbooks objBooks = objApp.Workbooks;
Workbook objBook = objBooks.Open(..)
// Do something (read data...)
...
objBook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
objApp.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objBooks);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objApp);
objBook = null;
objApp = null;
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

But after above process, i check in Task Manager, EXCEL.EXE process still alive, don't be killed. Please tell me why, help me a solution!!!

Comment: There should be a quit method in the ApplicationClass instance.

Comment: I miss this method, I really called this method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly clean up Excel interop objects in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c)

Comment: I did like that (as my code above), but can't resolve my problem. Please advance help me.

Answer (score 0):

How about this code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out IntPtr ProcessId);
```

After all your code and when you think there is no need of `excel` file write this code

```
IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(ExcelObj.Hwnd); // Your Excel Application name
IntPtr processId;
IntPtr foo = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processId);
Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(processId.ToInt32());
proc.Kill();
```